# kivy transition between screens

Tags: python, kivy

i made a gui with python kivy with a starting screen that has a button in it which generates new screens when pressed, and it also generates new buttons so its easier to pick the screen i need to get in focus but i can't get it working properly cause i can't generate buttons on the newly made screens
when they aren't in focus, the script only generates buttons for the screen in focus it seems

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

    
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenManagement, self).__init__(**kwargs)

sm = ScreenManagement(transition=FadeTransition())        
         
      
class newtab(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(newtab, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        self.bt1=(Button(text="New tab", size_hint =(.1, .1)          ,pos_hint ={'center_x':.1, 'center_y':.94}))
        self.add_widget(self.bt1)
        self.bt1.bind(on_release=self.new_tab)
        
        
        self.txt1 = TextInput(text='',size_hint =(.1, .1),        pos_hint ={'center_x':.2, 'center_y':.75}, multiline=True)
        self.add_widget(self.txt1)
        

            
    def transition(self, instance):
        self.manager.current = (instance.text)
        for item in sm.screen_names:
            
            self.bt2=(Button(text=item, size_hint =(.1, .1)          ,pos_hint ={'center_x':(.1*sm.screen_names.index(item)+.1), 'center_y':.84}))
            self.add_widget(self.bt2)
            self.bt2.bind(on_release=self.transition)
        
    def new_tab(self, *args):
                
        n = len(self.manager.screen_names)    ##number of screens+1
        screen = newtab(name="screen {}".format(n))      #make new screen and give it number
        self.manager.add_widget(screen)
        self.manager.current = "screen 0"
               
        for item in sm.screen_names:            
            self.bt2=(Button(text=item, size_hint =(.1, .1)          ,pos_hint ={'center_x':(.1*sm.screen_names.index(item)+.1), 'center_y':.84}))
            self.add_widget(self.bt2)
            self.bt2.bind(on_release=self.transition)

            
sm.add_widget(newtab(name='screen 0'))    
             
class Application(App):
    def build(self):       
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application().run()
```

Comment: There is a built-in widget [`TabbedPanel`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.tabbedpanel.html#module-kivy.uix.tabbedpanel) having functionalities that perhaps you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that below is what you expected to get. But I agree with [@ApuCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17375573/apucoder) that you may look for [TabbedPanel](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.tabbedpanel.html) functionality.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenManagement, self).__init__(**kwargs)

sm = ScreenManagement(transition=FadeTransition())

class newtab(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(newtab, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.bt1 = (Button(text="New tab", size_hint=(.1, .1), pos_hint={'center_x': .1, 'center_y': .94}))
        self.add_widget(self.bt1)
        self.bt1.bind(on_release=self.new_tab)

        self.txt1 = TextInput(text='', size_hint=(.1, .1), pos_hint={'center_x': .2, 'center_y': .75}, multiline=True)
        self.add_widget(self.txt1)

        # add all present screen buttons to newly created screen
        for i, screen in enumerate(sm.screens):
            self.bt2 = (Button(text=screen.name, size_hint=(.1, .1), pos_hint={'center_x': (.1 * i + .1), 'center_y': .84}))
            self.add_widget(self.bt2)
            self.bt2.bind(on_release=self.transition)

        # add this newly created screen button to all screens
        for screen in sm.screens + [self]:
            screen.bt2 = (Button(text=self.name, size_hint=(.1, .1), pos_hint={'center_x': (.1 * len(sm.screens) + .1), 'center_y': .84}))
            screen.add_widget(screen.bt2)
            screen.bt2.bind(on_release=screen.transition)

    def transition(self, instance):
        self.manager.current = instance.text

    def new_tab(self, *args):
        n = len(self.manager.screen_names)  ##number of screens+1
        screen = newtab(name="screen {}".format(n))  # make new screen and give it number
        self.manager.add_widget(screen)
        self.manager.current = "screen 0"

sm.add_widget(newtab(name='screen 0'))

class Application(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application().run()
```